# Change the image that is taken in the facebook send box

Tags: facebook, image, send

when I create a send button, the facebook api find an image that i don´t want to be the icon of the shared page. In appereance facebook take a nearby image and use it in the box. It is possible to cheat facebook so it use the image I want?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically set the image you want to use.  If not, then the application will just take the first image it comes across on your page.  You set an image for the page by setting specific metatags in the page header.  For information on the various metatags, see this [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/).

You can also paste url current URL into the [facebook debugging tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it will tell you what image it will use and offer suggestions on which meta tags need to be added.